Google Cloud Functions Python multithreading
I'm writing a Google Cloud Function in Python that performs a bunch of network requests, which I previously did sequentially but now want to change to doing them in parallel. I am trying to implement this using the threading library, and running my code locally works just fine. However, it causes my function to time out (which I can't make sense of) when I deploy it. I do not get any error messages. Is there a reason for this? Here is the structure of my code
 def do(args, results):
    result = networkRequest()
    results[key] = result

@functions_framework.http
def segmentMaps(request):    
   maps = {}

   threads = []
   for a in arr:
      t = threading.Thread(target=do, args=(stuff, maps))
      threads.append(t)
      t.start()

  for t in threads:
     t.join()

  return results

Thanks!

Have a look at this Stackoverflow Link and thread.
